# Hibernate validator doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, hibernate-validator

I'm using Hibernate validator with Hibernate and Spring, but it seems that validations don't work. When I don't enter a String or enter a String of 1 character (which is not between `min=4` and `max=20`) is not showing any error and therefore saves in the table. What am I missing?

```
package dao;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name="etudiant")
public class Etudiant {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID_ETUDIANT")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long idEtudiant;

    @Column(name="NOM")
    @Size (min=4, max=20)
    private String nom;

    @Size(min=4, max=20, message="nom doit etre entre 4 et 20 svp..")
    @Column(name="PRENOM")
    private String prenom;

    @Column(name="DATE_NAISSANCE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateNaissance;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    private String email;

    public Etudiant() {
        super();
    }

    public Long getIdEtudiant() {
        return idEtudiant;
    }

    public void setIdEtudiant(Long idEtudiant) {
        this.idEtudiant = idEtudiant;
    }

    public Etudiant(String nom, String prenom, Date dateNaissance, String email) {
        super();
        this.nom = nom;
        this.prenom = prenom;
        this.dateNaissance = dateNaissance;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    public Date getDateNaissance() {
        return dateNaissance;
    }

    public void setDateNaissance(Date dateNaissance) {
        this.dateNaissance = dateNaissance;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="save",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String  saveetudient(Model md,
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("etudiant") Etudiant et, 
        BindingResult res) {
    if (res.hasErrors()) {
        List <Etudiant> ets=service.listeEtudiants();
        md.addAttribute("etudiants",ets);
        return "etudiant1";
    }
    else {
        service.addEtudiant(et);
        List <Etudiant> ets=service.listeEtudiants();
        md.addAttribute("etudiants",ets);
        return "etudiant1";
    }
}
```

In JSP I put this line to show errors:

```
<form action="save" method="post">

  <table border="1" width="500" bgcolor="grey">

 <tr> 

 <th>Nom </th>
<th>Prenom </th>
<th> Date de naissance</th>
<th>Email </th>
</tr>


<tr> 
 <td>  <input type="text" name="nom" >   </td>
 <td> <input type="text" name="prenom" >  </td>
 <td>  <input type="text" name="dateNaissance" > </td>
  <td> <input type="text" name="email" >  </td>
 </tr>

 </table>  <br>
 <input type="submit" value="ajouter">

 <sform:errors path="etudiant.*"/>
 <sform:errors path="prenom"/> 
</form>
```

XML file configuration :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd ">

<context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean class="dao.DaoEtudiantImpl" name="daoetud"></bean>

<bean class="service.EtudiantMetierImpl" name="servetud">
  <property name="dao"  ref="daoetud"></property>
</bean>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

  <bean id="viewResolver"        
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
<property name="prefix">
    <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
 </property>
 <property name="suffix">
  <value>.jsp</value>

 </property>
```

Comment: why do have on field and getter?

Comment: Sorry I took it off from the getter, I was just trying something .just updated

Comment: I haven't used hibernate for a while. Are the min and max really for String length or are they for numbers?

Comment: @Mukus see http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/

Comment: @BenamarB. Is any validation working?

Comment: no validation working , Min and Max are for String .

Comment: can you show your full form , and what happens when you change

<sform:errors path="prenom"/>

Comment: @kuhajeyan I just updated , I put the full form

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I found the error ,
the problem was that I didin't add  **hibernate-validator jar** I only added files in the dist/lib/required :

- classmate-1.3.1
- javax.el-2.2.4
  -javax.el-api-2.2.2
- jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final
- validation-api-1.1.0

  So if that happens to someone just add : hibernate-validator-5.3.2.Final.

Comment: Just a tip, you can check if HV is properly initialized in the first place by checking for the following log line at app startup (this is from a Spring Boot app, but other platforms should also probably display it): `[background-preinit]  INFO Version HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.5.Final`

Answer (score 2):

After spent one hour to study two validation tutorials:

[Hibernate Validator Annotations Example](http://javabycode.com/java-frameworks/hibernate-4-tutorial/hibernate-validator-annotations-example.html)

[Spring MVC Form Validation Annotation Example](http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-mvc-tutorial/spring-mvc-form-validation-annotation-example.html)

I suggest you some solutions.

1) Verify hibernate validation annotation working or not

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();    
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();   
Set<ConstraintViolation<Etudiant>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(etudiant);
```

2) You can create custom validator, for example EtudiantValidator, then validate manually like below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="save",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String  saveetudient(Model md,@ModelAttribute("etudiant") Etudiant etudiant, BindingResult res){
    new EtudiantValidator().validate(etudiant, result);
    ...
}
```

However I deep into your code,I see that you have a mistake on this method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="save",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String  saveetudient(Model md,
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("etudiant") Etudiant et, 
        BindingResult res)
```

Should change it to like below

```
@RequestMapping(value="save",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String  saveetudient(Model md,
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("etudiant") Etudiant etudiant, 
        BindingResult res)
```

Hope this help!

Comment: thanks for your suggestions.I changed what you suggest but doesn't change. to verify if hibernate validator  annotation is working, i didn t understand , please can you give me more details on how to do it .

Comment: Validator annotation works fine so that this problem come from Spring side. Let's see Spring stuffs on the tutorial that I linked